Weirdness with `\ifnum`: `\ifnum\curyear=2024` gives an error, but `\ifnum2024=\curyear` works as expected
After an embarrassing amount of attempted research and trial and error, I've landed on the following code that works as expected. If the current year is 2024, it says "They match!". If it's not, it says "They don't".
\documentclass[paper=letter, fontsize=11pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\def\curyear{\the\year{}}
\ifnum2024=\curyear
They match!
\else
They don't.
\fi

\end{document}

On the other hand, the following code (which seems equivalent and more intuitive to me) doesn't work.
\documentclass[paper=letter, fontsize=11pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\def\curyear{\the\year{}}

\ifnum\curyear=2024
They match!
\else
They don't.
\fi

\end{document}

Compiling this results in the errors ! Missing = inserted for \ifnum. and ! Missing number, treated as zero..
To add insult to injury, the pdf that's produced has the wrong result; it says "They don't." instead of "They match!". I presume the "treated as zero" from the error message means that this occurred because 2024 doesn't equal 0.
What I find even stranger than all that is the fact that \ifnum{2024}=\curyear produces a similar error.
My question is twofold

What gives? Can anybody explain why the two sides of the equals sign behave differently here?
Where should I (or the next person with superficial familiarity with LaTeX who runs into this problem) have looked? I did my best to scan through TeX by Topic for an answer but got nowhere; I can't definitively say that the answer wasn't in there somewhere. Was there some manual I could have consulted for this kind of thing? Does anyone have a good reference for this kind of detail on how LaTeX conditionals work?


Since you already looked into TeX by Topic: You can see both \year and \ifnum are documented there.

\ifnum⟨number₁⟩⟨relation⟩⟨number₂⟩ ⟨expandable command⟩ Test relations between numbers.

Where ⟨number⟩ is defined to be

An important part of the grammar of TEX is the rigorous definition of a ⟨number⟩, the
syntactic entity that TEX expects when semantically an integer is expected. This definition
will take the largest part of this chapter. Towards the end, \count registers, arithmetic, and
tests for numbers are treated.

and other things like

⟨number⟩⟶⟨optional signs⟩⟨unsigned number⟩
⟨optional signs⟩⟶⟨optional spaces⟩
| ⟨optional signs⟩⟨plus or minus⟩⟨optional spaces⟩


Here \year is defined to be

\year ⟨integer parameter⟩The year of the current job.

and \the is defined to be

\the⟨internal quantity⟩⟨primitive command⟩Expand the value of various
quantities in TEX into a string of (character) tokens.

The exact definition of ⟨internal quantity⟩ is not in TeX by Topic, and is left as an exercise in TeXbook whose answer is

⟨internal quantity⟩⟶⟨internal integer⟩| ⟨internal dimen⟩
| ⟨internal glue⟩| ⟨internal muglue⟩| ⟨internal nonnumeric⟩

where the first case ⟨internal integer⟩ have \year belongs to.
Formally writing down the grammar may not be very enlightening (unfortunately), but I don't know what is a better way.

Anyway, there's no ⟨left brace⟩ or ⟨right brace⟩ or ⟨general text⟩ etc. anywhere in the definition of \ifnum.
On the other hand, a ⟨number⟩ by definition ends with an ⟨optional spaces⟩ (that part is actually ambiguous, since there is at most one space token being taken), which might not be convenient to work with. You may prefer \int_compare:nNnTF from expl3 instead, whose grammar is

\int_compare:nNnTF
{⟨int expr1⟩} ⟨relation⟩ {⟨int expr2⟩}
{⟨true code⟩} {⟨false code⟩}

Here one pair of braces around each of the ⟨int expr⟩ is required. (For what it's worth, the grammar for ⟨int expr⟩ is more complicated than TeX's ⟨number⟩ in that it allows things like +, but that is not particularly relevant here.)

By the way, \year is an internal integer, and while it cannot be printed out to the document directly without \the, \ifnum can happily takes an internal integer. So you could just write \ifnum\year=2024  (trailing space intended) or \ifnum2024=\year.

Even more helpful than your comment. Perhaps one day I will find the time and patience to slowly make my way through TeX by Topic. In the mean time, this clears up a lot of my misconceptions

Sorry, but there's no weirdness. The primitive \ifnum works by expanding the following tokens until finding something that qualifies for
<number> <relation> <number>

In your “weird” case, the first expansion step leads to
(\ifnum)\the\year{}=2024

The \ifnum is in parentheses because TeX has already stored it and now it's looking for tokens satisfying the requirements. Now TeX sees that \the is expandable and expands it, finding
(\ifnum)2024{}=2024

Bummer! There is a number, but there's something after it that TeX can neither expand nor interpret as a relation.
You're probably misunderstanding what {} does. When you want to print the current year, you can use
We're in \curyear{} and something went wrong.

because the braces will do no harm as they just open and close a group with no consequences on the typesetting; the net effect is that the space after } isn't ignored. They aren't innocuous terminators or indicators that the command has no argument.
You also see that the braces after \year aren't needed (and are actually dangerous).
However, there is something more on this. Assuming you define
\def\curyear{\the\year}

you shouldn't use \curyear in \ifnum tests. Try
\def\curyear{\the\year}
\ifnum 2025>\curyear
  2025 will be a nice year%
\else
  we hope for the best%
\fi
\bye

and compile with pdftex, you may be surprised to see

we hope for the best

I'm not surprised because I prepared the example knowing exactly what would happen: TeX is comparing 2025 with 20242025. Let's see why: the token list TeX will be fed with is
\ifnum 2025>\curyear 2025•will•be•a•nice•year\else we•hope•for•the•best\fi

where bullets denote space tokens (and spaces are just used to show where symbolic token names end); note that there is no space token after \curyear, because the endline in input will be ignored as it follows a control sequence. Now TeX finds the first number and the relation and starts looking (expanding tokens) for the second number:
(\ifnum 2025>)\the\year 2025•will•be•a•nice•year\else we•hope•for•the•best\fi

Now \the is expandable and we get
(\ifnum 2025>)20242025•will•be•a•nice•year\else we•hope•for•the•best\fi

as announced. Note that if you do
\def\curyear{\the\year}
\ifnum \curyear<2025
  2025 will be a nice year%
\else
  we hope for the best%
\fi
\bye

the test would succeed because the endline after 2025 is not ignored and will be transformed into a space token.
Never use \the when passing numbers to \ifnum for comparison. Both forms of the test would succeed if you just use \year instead of \curyear.

The other answer got me most of the way there, but this answer breaks things down very nicely and very explicitly addresses my misconceptions about curly braces. Thank you!

I partially figured out the problem, thought it would be worth sharing for posterity. I'm still curious about why putting braces around 2024 results in an error and still interested in any references.

After seeing this question, I had incorrectly assumed that \the\year required a terminal {} in order to produce a number. In fact, \the\year produces the year on its own, and the additional {} was supplied in order to prevent the space that comes after from being ignored, as is explained here.
This distinction doesn't matter if you're obliviously typing things into a document, but (I think that) \ifnum parsed \curyear as supplying 2024 and then an empty argument (where there would normally be one of =, <, >). On the other hand, the following code functions exactly as expected.
\documentclass[paper=letter, fontsize=11pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\def\curyear{\the\year}
\ifnum2024=\curyear
They match!
\else
They don't.
\fi

\end{document}


\year is an ⟨internal quantity⟩, \ifnum is an TeX primitive which isn't happy with random braces. Reference would have to be found in TeXbook or TeX by Topic then (or if they're not sufficiently clear, TeX engine's source code)

@user202729 Is it generally true that TeX primitives react poorly to extra braces? If so, that's good to know

It's… up to the primitive. For example \setbox or \halign requires the braces at appropriate places.

@user202729 Oh, the joys of TeX. This has been enlightening, thank you
